# Gitignore the current modifications but keep the old versions in the repo

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore the modifications to the config files in my {project_dir}/application/config/{all config files and sub directories}. But I want the older version files and sub dirs to be in the repo i.e I just want the modifications I made to several config files not to be pushed to the repo. So, can anyone tell me how to gitignore my config dir so that all the changes I make inside it are ignored without affecting the current files and sub dirs in the repo.

I've tried these in my `.gitignore` file in project root dir and its not working:

```
/application/vendor/
application/vendor
application/vendor/*
application/vendor/**
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, it looks like you want to ignore changes made to certain files locally, while there might be upstream changes. In that case, you can run

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

to make git ignore any local changes to the file.

Then when you want to track changes again, you can do:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

Note that if the file in question gets changed via upstream commits, you will need to run the second command before doing a git pull, since otherwise you might get merge conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

`.gitignore` itself won't remove any files. It just ignore any changes, until you issue a `git rm --cached`.

I also recommend you to put the ignores in `.git/info/exclude`, so it's available exclusive to your clone.

Anyway, the answer should be simple (if I understood correctly):

```
/application/config/**
```